# ZF2 SQL Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am trying to get suggestions for a string being typed to create a prediction.

What I want is to have a like statement but allow the user to write parts of a name and get the suggestions. So for example, if I have a name in the DB of "joe bloggs" and  a user types "jo b" it comes up with the suggestion?

```
public function getSuggestions($part)
{
    $where = new Where();    
    $where->like('name', '%'.$part.'%');
    return $this->select($where)->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always a quick solution when staring, probably not the best but this works:

```
public function getSuggestions($part)
{
    $where = new Where();    
    $part = str_replace(' ', '%', $part);
    $where->like('name', '%'.$part.'%');
    return $this->select($where)->toArray();
}
```